# Use beautifulsoup to extract href with defined text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<form action="/2811457/follow?gsid=3_5bce9b871484d3af90c89f37" method="post">
<div>
<a href="/2811457/follow?page=2&amp;gsid=3_5bce9b871484d3af90c89f37">next_page</a>
&nbsp;<input name="mp" type="hidden" value="3" />
<input type="text" name="page" size="2" style='-wap-input-format: "*N"' />
<input type="submit" value="jump" />&nbsp;1/3
</div>
</form>
```

I have search on STO,many people ask how to extract text between tags
I wanna to know how to extract href by giving a defined text.

In above html file,I want to extract "/2811457/follow?page=2&gsid=3_5bce9b871484d3af90c89f37" by give a text of "next_page".

what I have done is like:

```
  t = soup1.findAll(text=re.compile(r'next_page'))
  s = t.parent
  print s.nextSibling['href']
```

It return None

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two minor corrections.  Use *find* instead of *findAll*.  Instead of calling *nextSibling*, lookup the *href* attribute using the *get* method:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> import re
>>> page = '''\
<form action="/2811457/follow?gsid=3_5bce9b871484d3af90c89f37" method="post">
<div>
<a href="/2811457/follow?page=2&amp;gsid=3_5bce9b871484d3af90c89f37">next_page</a>
&nbsp;<input name="mp" type="hidden" value="3" />
<input type="text" name="page" size="2" style='-wap-input-format: "*N"' />
<input type="submit" value="jump" />&nbsp;1/3
</div>
</form>
'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
>>> soup.find(text=re.compile(r'next_page')).parent.get('href')
u'/2811457/follow?page=2&gsid=3_5bce9b871484d3af90c89f37'
```